# How to pass session into views in Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am playing around with Node/Express 3.0. But I am not sure how to get session out. Especially I am not sure if I am doing right with the following in routes/session.js.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});
```

The followings are more details.

I have this in app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  ;

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('testtest'));
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'testtest',
    maxAge: 3600000
  }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
...
require ('./routes/session')(app);
...
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

And in routes/session.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });

  app.get('/session/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('session/new', {title: "Log in"});
  });

  app.post('/session', function(req, res) {
    if (users[req.body.username] && 
      users[req.body.username].password === req.body.password) {
        req.session.user = users[req.body.username];
        res.redirect('/users');
      } else {
        res.redirect('/session/new')
      }
  });

  app.del('/session', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/users');
  });

};
```

I have this in view.

```
- if (session.user) {

  p
    span Hello&nbsp;
    span= session.user.name
    span= session
    span !
  p
    form(method="POST", action="/session")
      input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="DELETE")
      input(type="submit", value="Log out")

- } else {

  p
    a(href="/session/new") Login
    span &nbsp;or&nbsp;
    a(href="/users/new") Register

- }
```

But this does not pick up session and gives an error.

```
1| > 2| - if (session.user) { 3| 4| p 5| span Hello  session is not defined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the middleware approach to work, you need to make sure your `app.use` call that installs the middleware is done before your call to `app.use(app.router);`.  Currently you're calling it after via the `require('./routes/session')(app);` call:

```
require ('./routes/session')(app);
app.use(app.router);
```

To do this without middleware, change your `res.render` call to pass in the local `session` variable you want available to the view:

```
app.get('/session/new', function(req, res) {
  res.render('session/new', {title: "Log in", session: req.session});
});
```

Comment: This means I have to add session: req.session to all. Why can't I use res.locals?

Comment: @shin Sorry, I added a solution for the middleware approach to the answer.

Comment: O my Gosh! Guys, you saved my life. You are the first from tens of others who said that it should be called before app.use(app.router). Can you please explain it? Or is it clearly seen from express' code?